# WPF MVVM architecture, what is the best practice communicate between model and viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, architecture, signalr

We are developing a TODO list kind of application in WPF

1)when user logs in we load list of workitem for the user(only basic details)

2)when user opens particular workitem we load all its information from service

3)we use signalr to add new workitem to the user when he is working on the system (singalr will
send the workitemid, and based on it we will fetch basic detail and add it to the workitem list)

Whenever user edits the workitem, if he changes anything in the workitem information, we should move it to UnSaved List, and if he reverts it we need to move the workitem to Opened List

1)when user enters something in screen it directly alters model (letsay workitem model has user model and user model has firstname, this firstname is bound to the textbox), how to communicate this change
to the viewmodel, so that viewmodel will move this workitem to unsaved list.

To find out a workitem is dirty or not, we are keeping Unchanged workitem details inside each workitem, so whenever user changes something in screen we make comparision with this unchanged workitem and move it to unsave or opened list.

2)Is it right approach to have Unchanged workitem inside each workitem, are there any best approach or pattern available?

3)how to differentiate between user changing some value of workitem and system changing values of workitem

let say A and B user sees the same workitem in edit mode, User A edits some value in workitem and
saves it, now user B will receive this information through signalr notification, and we will make a call to service based on this workitemid and will populate the changes in B's screen. Now we should not move the workitem to unsaved list, because changes are done by system.

4)Moreover we will recieve lot of signalr notification related to multiple workitems, we don't
want to make multiple service call as and when signalr notification comes, but whenever user clicks on workitem we would like to see the changes done in that workitem from other user. What is the efficient way of doing this. (We don't want notification to contain all the information, we kept only the Id and type of the notification, so that signalr will be as lean as possible)

5)how to compensate for singalr notification failiures, (we could make some kind of timer which will periodically poll list of notifications based on the last arrived notificationid).
Is this a good approach or any pattern exist for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if I understand your questions.
So conceptionaly I think you are thinking about a real-time collaboration sort of software.
There are patterns and algorithm how this is solved in a distributed fashion. You should look for the papers of the google wave protocol (the foundation of the real time editing feature of the google docs tools) http://www.waveprotocol.org/whitepapers. Or research for Operational Transformation: https://operational-transformation.github.io/.

The good think is that there are already libraries out there which handle protocols like this and adapt or extend these concepts.

But finding the right library for handling realtime callobrative work over signalrs whould be a huge win. Don't know if there is also a library that builds on top of signalrs - might be worth a google or bing session.

But I think before you talk about technical details as c# or mvvm it would be a good start to understand the background of real time collaborative communication in distributed systems.

Like I said I hope I got your question correct  and since you did not post any source code there is no chance to be more precise...

HTH and leads you into the right direction.